# how to upload image with ajax Extjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

i want to upload image using ajax request.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: SITE_URL+'upload/',
    headers: {'Content-type':'multipart/form-data'},
    form: filefield.up('form').getForm(), 
    isUpload: true,
    success: function(response, options) { console.log(arguments); },
    failure: function(response, options) { console.log(arguments); }
});
```

my filefield is inside the form. but it rasing up an error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setAttribute'
```

how to resolve this? help me please.

Comment: i use onFilefieldChange to triggering the ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `form` option for `Ext.Ajax.request` is expecting a DOM form. Instead, you should use the `submit` method on the form:

```
filefield.up('form').getForm().submit({
    url: 'foo'
});
```

Comment: i have try this, but my problem now, how to capture upload progress.. (display in percentage)